# How do I pass a Swift class to an Objective-C method needing a Class?

Tags: swift

I'm looking to use the Objective-C library [saxy](https://github.com/reaster/saxy) to parse some XML into objects, however the method signature is:

```
+ (id)rootXPath:(NSString *)xpath toMany:(Class)toType nsURI:(NSString *)nsURI;
```

I'm having trouble working out how I'd pass the Class object type as Swift does not seem to work with classes in this way. As a workaround I will probably make the domain model + a wrapper in Objective-C, but would be good to know if there's a way to do it in pure Swift.

I've tried the following, but I get a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION:

```
OXmlElementMapper.rootXPath("/route", toMany: Route.self, nsURI: "")
```

and this which produces a syntax error:

```
OXmlElementMapper.rootXPath("/route", toMany: Route.Type, nsURI: "")
```

Comment: did you solved your problem of passing Class to Objective C api from Swift? I am facing the same issue and I tried passing MyClass.self. But this doesn't seems to be working. I am using Xcode 7 Beta 6.

Comment: @dshah, afraid not. I haven't done swift in a long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MyClass.self` *is* the correct way to reference a class, but perhaps you're missing `@objc` on the class?

See [docs regarding interop](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_36)

Comment: You're quite right - the .self passing wasn't the problem. Looks like there is a bad cast coming out of that method.. thanks for the point in the right direction!