# How to pass a Swift class in Objective C api expecting the Class type

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swift2

I have following API in Objective C declared in protocol:

```
-(id)decodeData:(NSData *)data inType:(Class)className error:(NSError **)error;
```

Now, I have implemented a class in Swift that implements ObjC protocol as below:

```
@objc class XMLDeserializer: NSObject, IDeserializer {

    @objc func decodeData(data: NSData!, inType className: AnyClass!) throws -> AnyObject {

    }
}
```

Now, my Swift class method is called from within the Objective C class as a part of protocol method calling. But, it is NOT Called.

What could be the reason?

**Update:**

I have my Communicator class where I have the serializer property in it. When I give my custom serializer object to that property, it is expected that it will call the protocol method (when the success response will come) as described above.

From my communicator class, below is the code how I call my protocol method:

```
responseObject = [self.responseSerializer decodeData:dataToDeserialize inType:self.responseType error:&err];
```

I have checked and printed the output in console from NSData in Comms Class, to verify that I am getting the successful response.

Only concern is that, my custom serializer is plugged into communicator and then also, my protocol method is not getting called.

I found similar question: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112098/how-do-i-pass-a-swift-class-to-an-objective-c-method-needing-a-class?noredirect=1#comment52704391_24112098) but that didn't solved my problem because passing `MyClass.self` will append the module name in that argument.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: How do you expect it to be called? Who is calling the method?

Comment: What are the exclamation marks for?

Comment: what use of that throws keyword here?

Comment: show the code how did you call this method in ObjectiveC.

Comment: How do you know any empty method isn't called?

Comment: Please see my updated question.. Hope I have cleared all your queries. If not, please let me know what more info you need.

Comment: One more thing, I can think of is because passing the Class type from Swift to Objective C will carry the Module name as well and hence Objective C can't find that class? I am not sure, if SDK will manage it or not.

Comment: @matt: Exclamation marks are for unwrapped optionals.

Comment: @Shoaib: In Swift, my API of objc is exposed as this syntax to Swift 2.

Comment: What I'm asking is: do you really believe that you'll be called with a nil `data` or a nil `className`?

Comment: @matt: I got your point. Actually, for certain data types like those supported by NSJSONSerialization, I am passing `nil` in class type. (I have designed in that way). For data, I will never pass the `nil`. I will look into that, once I will solve this main problem. Thanks for making me clear in that respect.